# Hadoop Streaming gives null for each word count record

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I wrote a simple word count program for use with Hadoop Streaming.
I tested the program locally and it gives expected results.
With Hadoop Streaming however it distinguishes all the words but gives null for the count.

Here is code used for word count mapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    data_list = line.split("\t")
    if (len(data_list) >= 3):
        if ('actor' in str(data_list[3])):
            print data_list[0]
```

Here is reducer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys


word_dict = {}


for line in sys.stdin:
    v = line.strip()
    if word_dict.has_key(v):
        word_dict[v] += 1
    else:
        word_dict[v] = 1

print 'tconst' + "\t" + 'actors'
for key in word_dict:
    print str(key) + "\t" + str(word_dict[key])
```

And here is the command I use

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-file mapper.py  -mapper 'python mapper.py' \
-file reducer.py  -reducer 'python reducer.py' \
-input input/datasource1 \
-output output_mr3 \
-outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat\
```

How can I modify the code to get the word count working?

Comment: Acc to me, the error is coming because you haven't used the output of mapper function in reducer function anywhere.  Please follow this doc once and see if it helps. [link] (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hadoop-streaming-using-python-word-count-problem/) @mateuszs

Comment: Also please check the use of "actor" in mapper function and "actors" in print in reducer function. Maybe it is causing some ambiguity in the structure of code